# Is there any handy way to inspect whether a xml file contins invalid characters

Tags: java, xml

I am writing a Java program that parses/unmarshals XML files to Java objects.

This program takes XML files, which are generated by some third party and I do not have any control over of.

Upon getting the files, the program checks whether they are invalid format using their respective XSDs↓

```
URL schemaFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(xsd/some.xsd);
Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File(/path/to/xml));
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(xmlFile);
```

then starts parsing/unmarshalling them individually using JAXP.

The problem I am facing is that even after the validation above, sometimes I get the following error. (the validator above does not seem to check whether the XML contains invalid characters, but only compare the input with its XSD)

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[xxx,xxx]
```

Is there any handy way to inspect whether XML file contains invalid characters using programmatically or some tool?

I have extracted the portion(line 245) where the exception occurs using "sed -n '240,250p'".
[sample.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-niYnBmlT2taDFGZDJza2xNTTg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you envision a way that would not involve examining each character? Why can you not just handle the exception when it occurs?

Comment: I am not sure if that is how I should handle invalid characters. I am importing the XML data into a database for some purposes. (XML -> Java object -> database table). Wouldn't you think that those invalid characters cause unexpected side effects?

Comment: They will cause a parse exception. Don't commit until the entire input has been processed. It should be all or nothing.

Comment: I understand that. Actually what I want to know what exact character, which might be invisible characters, causes the exception maybe using some tool.

Comment: The exception tells you exactly where the error is.

Comment: yes, I have already looked into where the exception tells the error is, but I can't find any invalid character. I tried "cat -etv". I am wondering if the exception might be thrown upon other than invalid characters.

Comment: Could you please attach a sample of input file?

Comment: I have attached a sample. I can't attach the whole document as it contains some sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a whitelist of allowed characters? Here's one pattern:

1. For each streamed character, if it is not whitelisted replace it with nothing.
2. Ask whether your file content after filtering is the same as before (diff pattern)

If the content in both files is not equal then the source file had invalid characters.